# POST request from Swift fails while it works in Postman

Tags: ios, swift

I've a django REST api which works perfectly when called over POSTMAN or an android client. However when I try to call it in Swift I get a 405.

This is my code,

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/xx/x/xxx/sports")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "client_id=xx&client_secret=yy"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {return}
    do{
        //try validate(response)
        //parse data
        print(response)
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

    //print(String(describing: data))
}
task.resume()
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Another thing to check: Allows insecure HTTP loads in info.plist

Comment: I'm trying to call this on a playground.

Answer (score 2):

> 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request
>   method is known by the server but is not supported by the target
>   resource.
>
> The server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response
>   containing a list of the target resource's currently supported
>   methods.

Check the httpMethod. You may need `GET` or other HTTP method instead of `POST`

#### Update:

Replace 
`let postString = "client_id=xx&client_secret=yy"` 
with 
`let postString = "{client_id=\"xx\", client_secret=\"yy\"}"`

Also you should use **`URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)`** not with `url`. See the code below:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  if let response = response, let data = data {
    print(response)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
  } else {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

As you're using

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in...
```

Your `request` setup code is ignored. GET method is default, and it is not allowed on 
your server.

Comment: So I tried checking this using python and it works perfectly,
```>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post("http://example.com", data={"client_id": "xxx", "client_secret": "yyy"})
>>> r.status_code
200```

Comment: @MelissaStewart Try to replace `let postString = "client_id=xx&client_secret=yy"` with `let postString = "{client_id=\"xx\", client_secret=\"yy\"}"`

Answer (score 0):

> I've a django REST api which works perfectly when called over POSTMAN
>   or an android client.

If it is working on POSTMAN Then you can get that code from that itself. Copy that code and paste in Playground. It should work. 
Compare with your code. Fix the issues.